# Filtering in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm trying to filter my parameters in a condition where I have it choose a record when a multiple selection ListBox is selected. If a person doesn't select a record it by default chooses the "Not Selected" option. The issue is:

```
=IIF(
     InStr(Join(Parameters!ProvinceID.Value,”,”),0),
     True,
     IIF(
         InStr(Join(Parameters!ProvinceID.Value,”,”),
               Fields!ProvinceID.Value
         )<>0,
         True,
     False)
 )
```

The result wont allow the Proper filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
InStr(Join(Parameters!ProvinceID.Value,”,”),0)
```

Shouldn't that 0 be "0"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```vb
=IIf(
         InStr(Join(Parameters!ProvinceID.Value, ", "), "0") > 0
         ,True
         ,IIf(
                InStr(Join(Parameters!ProvinceID.Value, ", "), Fields!ProvinceID.Value) > 0,
                ,True
                ,False
             )
     )
```

---

`InStr` will return an integer value of the position where the string searched for starts (if found). Therefore your boolean tests (1st argument of the `IIf()` function) need to determine if a number equal to or greater than 1 has been returned.

- As you are searching for a string, the `0` being searched for in the string must be coded as `"0"`.
- If `Fields!ProvinceID.Value` returns an integer, then it too must be converted to a string using the `CStr()` function like so:

---

```vb
=IIf(
         InStr(Join(Parameters!ProvinceID.Value, ", "), "0") > 0
         ,True
         ,IIf(
                InStr(Join(Parameters!ProvinceID.Value, ", "), CStr(Fields!ProvinceID.Value)) > 0,
                ,True
                ,False
             )
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you comparing to? Usually the IIF needs something like =IIF(Fields!ListBox1.Value = "value",  "option1",  "option2")

=IIF(Fields!Eyes.Value = "Green", "Green", "Other Colour")